# How to parse user search string for Postgresql query?

Tags: php, postgresql, parsing, full-text-search, logical-operators

i created a search engine on my site using full text search in Postegresql.
i added a searchbox in my PHP page in which users can write strings like these:

```
word1 +word2
word1+word2
word1    -word2
 word1-word2
word1 word2
word1  word2
```

how to convert them to the following strings?

```
word1&word2
word1&word2
word1&!word2
word1&!word2
word1|word2
word1|word2
```

i tried several solutions but none works with all cases.
The last one i tried is the following:

```
    $user_query_string = trim($_GET['search']);
    $final_query_string = str_replace(array('+', ' ', '-'), array('&','|', '&!'), $user_query_string);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$a=array('word1 +word2','word1+word2','word1    -word2',' word1-word2','word1 word2','word1  word2');

foreach ($a as &$v) {
  $v=preg_replace('/ +/','|',        // last: change blanks to |
     preg_replace('/ *(?=[!&])/','', // delete blanks before ! or &
     strtr(trim($v),array('-'=>'&!','+'=>'&'))  // turn + and - into & and !&
     ));
}
print_r($a);
```

This will give:

```
Array
(
    [0] => word1&word2
    [1] => word1&word2
    [2] => word1&!word2
    [3] => word1&!word2
    [4] => word1|word2
    [5] => word1|word2
)
```