# How to split string on multiple delimiters keeping some delimiters?

Tags: php, regex, string, split, explode

i'm looking for a way to split a string in several words, based on some delimiters.

For example the string `word1&word2 !word3 word4 &word5` should give me an array with the following words:

```
word1
&word2
!word3
word4
&word5
```

How to reach that?
I tried several solution with str_replace() but i cannot figure out the best way to obtain what i need.
Maybe the solution could be using regular expressions, but i do not know how to use them.

Comment: you should look how to use explode, here http://php.net/explode

Comment: Obviously i have already seen that page but there isn't anything could help me. Am i wrong?

Comment: @keikoku92 `explode` will only work when there's a single consistent delimiter in the string like a comma. Here there are multiple possibilities.

Comment: you need to decide to one delimiter (for explode) or one rule. in your example this would be after each numeric character, is that what you mean?

Comment: as a board idea, you can 1) replace useless characters as &! or even the space character by a delimiter of your choice in your string and then explode it as it will have teh format needed

Comment: So no magic regex could solve this?

Comment: You can just split on spaces, or one of the non-word characters per lookahead `\s+|(?=\W)`. You need to be more specific on what constitutes a delimiter.

Comment: I think my example is self-explaining. It explains better that i could do.

Comment: You could use preg_split, as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452777/how-to-split-a-string-by-multiple-delimiters-in-php) answer.

Comment: You think bad, your example isn't clear at all and can be subject to many interpretations.

Comment: I have already seen that answer but as you can see i need to keep the delimiters attached to the splitted words.

Comment: I insist : create your own function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$src='word1&word2 !word3 word4 &word5';
$arr=explode(' ',$src=preg_replace('/(?<=[\w])([&!])/',' $1',$src));
echo join('<br>',$arr); // present the result ...
```

First change any occurence of a group consisting of a single character of class `[&!]` that is preceded by a 'word'-character into `' $1'` (=itself, preceded with a blank) and then `explode()`the string using the blanks as separators.

If you need to deal with multiple blanks as separators between the words you could of course replace the (faster) `explode(' ',...)` with a slighty more "refined" `preg_split('/ +/',...)`.

Comment: It works, but how to edit it if i encounter strings that contains `word1!word2`. In this case it doesn't split.

Comment: Just edited my reply: use a group consisting of a single character belonging to the character class `[&!]` instead of the single character `&` and replace it with its own occurence (`$1`) .

Comment: The reason for what i asked this it's because i'm trying to parse users search strings. Maybe you can help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760625/how-to-parse-user-search-string-for-postgresql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can do use of [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), and do some customization as needed. see example below:-

```
function customExplode($string){
    if($matches = preg_split('/[\s&!]+/i', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
        $return = array();
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $return[] = (($match[1]-1) >= 0) ? substr($string, $match[1]-1, 1).$match[0] : $match[0];
        }
        return $return;
    } else {
        return $string;
    }
}
$word = 'word1&word2 !word3 word4 &word5';
print_r(customExplode($word));
```

Results

```
Array
(
    [0] => word1
    [1] => &word2
    [2] => !word3
    [3] =>  word4
    [4] => &word5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers have overcomplicated this task.

The required coding/pattern logic is to split on each space OR on the position before `&` or `!`.

Code #1: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5TSn3)) - split on space or position between non-space and a `&` or `!`

```
var_export(
    preg_split('/ |(?<! )(?=[&!])/', $string)
);
```

Code #2: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IbMl2)) - hastily split on spaces or positions before `&` or `!` and omit empty elements from result

```
var_export(
    preg_split('/ |(?=[&!])/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Both Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'word1',
  1 => '&word2',
  2 => '!word3',
  3 => 'word4',
  4 => '&word5',
)
```